# Facebook SDK not included with Android App in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to add the facebook SDK to my project but it won't work at all.

I've followed the official steps; opened the fb sdk, made sure it's set to "is library", in m yown project go to properties->android->add library and it lets me select com_facebook_android and it shows up with a green tick next to it. HOWEVER, when i go back to that screen straight away it now has a red cross next to it, and if i try to launch the app in the emulator it has " com_facebook_android] Could not find com_facebook_android.apk!"

(This is just me testing without referencing the library in my app)

if i DO reference the library, then any calls to the facebook library give an error within eclipse and the tooltip suggests to add it to build path, so if i click that it launches fine, but still does the above apk error and the app force closes on any activity which references facebook.

As far as I can tell I'm following the official instructions fine but it just keeps coming back to that red cross in my app's properties

Does anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you have the issue, i've setup a empty project with facebook library in it, if you have no luck then try downloading that, unzipping it and importing exsiting project into workspace.

link : [Download here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwAnjRVwT4WzYTg3ZGMxMDAtZjUxYi00NTg5LTlkZGMtMTgzN2U0OWMzYTM4&hl=en_US&authkey=CLz35oAP)

Answer (score 1):

you know what i have done one trick to use the official facebook SDK in my application, i have created com.facebook.android and add all the library classes into it. Then i can easily reach to access any class whenever i want it. This can be a way to use the classes inside your application instead of using Library.

Its running fine in my case.